# Why aren't software companies required to make good faith efforts to enforce age restrictions?

Tags: software, terms-of-service, minor, age, fair-dealing

There are a lot of products and technologies available that support children asking for parental consent before purchases, etc.  (Amazon, Microsoft, etc...)

And, it really isn't that hard to do to confirm whether someone is an adult, (at least in the U.S. and with IDs).

***So, why aren't software companies, or at least their distributors, required to make good faith efforts to enforce age restrictions?***

For example, maybe an answer would address:

Do age restriction laws somehow indicate what a good-faith effort should look like? Or, do these laws not actually exist, therefore not requiring a good-faith effort?

I suppose this is more or less addressing the theories of good-faith practices to comply with laws, and not specifically this issue.

Comment: You mean...like Tencent in China? Where a software company can just make you enter in your Resident Identity Card? You should be able to easily understand why many people, and Americans in particular, would not appreciate this. Confirming age is one thing. Confirming *who* you are against a government database is quite another. And if a child has access to their parent's credit card info, what more do you really want or need? More personal info that the child would also have access to?

Comment: Why? Well, perhaps because no one has yet lobbied it hard enough for it to be enacted.

Comment: *It really isn't that hard to do to confirm whether someone is an adult* Are you sure about that? Can you provide a citation proving it? Even requiring a credit card is easily circumvented by a child stealing their parent's.

Comment: Because the legislative branch and relevant government agencies, in their wisdom, have decided not to require them to do so.

Comment: Many 10 year olds would be able to pass that kind of verification with a slight amount of dishonesty unless you involve things like fingerprints, notaries etc.

Comment: @StuartF - You asked for references, but there are quite a few drivers license verification APIs, (shared software libraries).  As for China, etc...  Domestic companies can be used for this, (like Steam, etc.).  Heck, it's even possible, (super easy), to do this through third parties anonymously without having to give personally identifying information, (Credit card companies do this like Visa, etc.).  Regardless, are age restrictions actually not mandated, and therefore good-faith efforts not required? Or, do laws themselves indicate what these efforts should look like?

Comment: @elikakohen ask yourself: how easy is it to get an adult's driver's license? I know mine is in my wallet all the time, and the wallet is in my pocket till I get to sleep. However, some of my relatives put their wallets on the counter once they are home, so the driver's license is in easy reach of an enterprising adolescent.

Comment: @elikakohen Sure, there are APIs that let you verify a driver's license. But that's not the question you asked; you asked about verifying an attribute of a _person_ using the computer, not an attribute of a driver's license. (If this doesn't make sense at first, think carefully about the difference between these two things.)

Comment: Are you sure about the open API to check driver's licenses? Maryland (for instance) requires a DPPA-approved reason to access records.

Comment: _As edited_, I believe this is fairly interpreted as an on-topic question about what age-restriction laws (in the US?) require.  The original did appear far more opinion-based.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the circumstances, companies may be required to make some effort. For example the Children's Online Privacy Protection Act  [15 U.S.C. §§ 6501–6506](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/15/chapter-91) (or see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Children%27s_Online_Privacy_Protection_Act)) provides for when website operators must obtain "verifiable parental consent".

Examples of how to obtain consent ([FTC](https://www.ftc.gov/business-guidance/resources/complying-coppa-frequently-asked-questions)):

- a consent form sent by mail, fax or scanned and emailed to the operator
- credit card, debit card, or other online payment system
- a toll-free telephone number or videoconference
- checking the parent's government-issued ID against the government ID database
- requiring the parent to answer a series of questions the non-parent would find difficult to answer
- Using facial recognition technology to compare a photo ID with another photo of the parent

Comment: Thanks!  This is what I was looking for.  Particularly general questions 11 & 12.  I did not know these rules were mostly about privacy, and children under 13.  This kind of makes it clear why companies don't do this, (because they don't really have to).  But, now I am wondering what Steam and many other companies are doing with all the personal information of minor children that they know they have.  For another day. ;)  Thanks again.

Answer (score 4):

First of all, the only real answer to "Why doesn't the law require this or that?" is "Because the legislature hasn't passed such a law." In the US, Congress or a state legislature could, if they chose to, pass such a law. I see nothing unconstitutional about it.

> And, it really isn't that hard to do to confirm whether someone is an adult, (at least in the U.S. and with IDs).

Actually, it is quite hard to confirm a person's real age and identity over the internet, if you assume that the person is willing to lie, and has access to a credit card and ID of an adult, which many teens can obtain if they wish. The usual means of validating age, say for entry into a bar, involve physical inspection of an ID, and comparison of it with the person by a trusted checker. Not easy over the net.

Answer (score 0):

For applications sold on Apple’s App Store, Apple lets me specify an age restriction, and I suppose that apple does something with that age restriction, although I have never checked what exactly. I assume ticking that box would be enough.

Anything beyond that, if it is more than just asking for the users age, is a *substantial* cost for a small company. Websites that really shouldn’t be viewed by anyone underage usually just have a button that says “yes, I’m 18 or over” and another that says “no, I’m not 18 yet”.

BTW Most people don’t check whether something is “suitable” for a four year old, but whether it’s “harmful”. So an introduction to Einstein’s general relativity theory will likely be available to four year olds.